# How to bypass when network speed over a special number in Juniper?

Tags: bgp, juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-mx

I have a requirement, such as I have `113.100.15.0/24` segment IP addresses.

in Juniper M480 Router I connected to BGP-A(`1G`) and BGP-B(`10G`),

by default the `113.100.15.0/24` out the Router it go through the BGP-A, but the BGP-A have a small bandwidth(only 1G), so there may well arise network congestion.

I have a requirement, for one IP of `113.100.15.0/24` if it beyond half of its limit bandwidth(or a specified number), the other traffic go BGP-B.

I mean if I have one IP `113.100.15.1/24` which out from BGP-A, if it's `100Mbps` network speed, if the IP network speed go beyond 50Mbps, then the beyond part out from BGP-B.

More explain, if `113.100.15.1/24` (100Mbps) out from BGP-A by default, if there comes 70Mbps network speed, the 50Mbps I want it out from BGP-A, the other 20Mbps I want it go out from BGP-B.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

BGP really isn't the tool to achieve this. Bandwidth utilisation is not one of the criteria which is used to select best paths.

If you really want to go down this path (and this can have huge drawbacks as well, balancing traffic can lead to a lot of packet reordering, routing instability and other problems), you should look into traffic optimizers. I am aware that some of these are able to influence routing tables by changing local preferences, injecting more specific routes and others tricks, but personally I wouldn't touch them with a 10 ft pole. Also, product recommendations are off topic here.